# How to compose an email with HTML in Flutter?

Tags: html, email, dart, flutter, document-body

I am using [flutter_email_sender](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_email_sender) to compose an email using the native iOS Mail app inside my Flutter app:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';
Future<void> sendEmail(String subject, String body) async {
  final Email email = Email(
    body: body,
    subject: subject,
  );
  String platformResponse;
  try {
    await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
    platformResponse = 'success';
  } catch (error) {
    platformResponse = error.toString();
  }
  if (!mounted) return;
  print(platformResponse);
}
```

However my goal is to send HTML in the body of the email. When I pass markup to `String body` the email is composed but not in markup, just text.

I am aware of [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) but that package launches the Mail app. I want the email composed as if I was calling [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller) in iOS.

Comment: The current version of flutter_email_sender sets the `isHTML` parameter of `MFMailComposeViewController` to `false`, so I guess no HTML for now. Have you tried `flutter_mailer`? It allows a custom value for `isHTML`, but it's a new project and the iOS support is marked as 'in progress'.

Comment: I have not - I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Just a point of reference... I delete automatically any email that has an HTML fork but not an equivalent text fork, as 95% of that email is just spam.

Comment: The package `flutter_mailer` shows promise but I could not make it work on iOS. I'm going to stick with `share`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that using [share](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share) one can select the standard iOS Mail app. If I pass HTML to this package, it will not launch the app separately, but will enable the user to compose the email inside the app, which is what I want:

```
Share.share('<html>Check out the <a href=\"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share\">share</a> Flutter package!</html>');
```